# How can I get the next or previous character of findText()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How can I get the next or previous character of `findText()`.

```
function myFunction() {
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var str = doc.getbody();
var i = "f";
var x = str.findText(i);
var y = str[str.index(x)-1];
Logger.log(y);
}
```

It is not working. and get some error.

Example: `string = "Abcdefgh" , var x=string.findText("f");` after found "f"; want to get previous char of "f". which is "e" in this case. I want to know special function in google script to get

Comment: What is `the next or previous character of findText()`? What is `the next or previous character of findText()`? Can you provide more detail information of your issue?

Comment: Thanks for reply, example, findText ("a"). then want to get character before text.   eg. tea word , system found "a" in the tea.  then get "e" in the tea which is before "a"

Comment: @HMA-user Would you please expand your question to give a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: example: string = "Abcdefgh"  , var x=string.findText("f");   after found "f"; want to get previous char of "f". which is "e" in this case. I want to know special function in google script to get .

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your issue, if you want to retrieve `e`, which is the previous value of `f`, by searching `f` from the string value of `Abcdefgh`, for example, when it declared `var string = "Abcdefgh"`, is the script you want this? `string[string.indexOf("f") - 1]`

Comment: function myFunction() {
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var str = doc.getbody();
var i = "f";
var x = str.findText(i);
var y = str[str.index(x)-1];
Logger.log(y);
} But not working

Comment: @HMA Why?`````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 2):

#### Flow:

- `getBody()` returns a body `object`. You need `string` type. `getText()` returns string.
- Use `regexp#exec` to get previous and next character of the search string

#### Snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var str = doc.getBody().getText();//modified
  var search = "f";
  var regx = new RegExp("(.)"+search+"(.)")
  var y = regx.exec(str);
  Logger.log(y);
  if (y !== null){ Logger.log("Previous character" + y[1]).log("Next character:" + y[2])}
}
```

#### To practice:

- [Regexp#exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)
- [Doc#body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getText())